# Handling complexity and size of winforms with about 100 forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am at the design stage of a Winforms application that might have about 100 separate forms. Security is not a concern. The application may access a local database. No LAN or networking is required. Each form may launch sub-forms. Each main form represent 1 business function. The forms will be launched from 1 master form. I was thinking of having each form as a separate .exe and exchange data (most data exchanged is less than 10Ks) using temporary files. This way, each form can be built separately instead of embedding all the forms into the master form.

I am sure there are more complex applications and much better architecture, your help is appreciated.

The question here is: What is the best simple way to architect an application with so many forms without having all the forms in 1 project or is that OK memory wise and performance wise?

Note: Of course I am not looking for code, an idea or a reference will suffice.
Thanks.

Comment: you can have separate projects in the **same** solution that are compiled to .dll, but AFAIK windows does not load the whole executable into memory anyway.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, thank your for your comment, but it becomes cumbersome to manage the project and may cause the size to be large (I assume so at least).

Comment: @Slai, this sounds good but could those DLLs have forms? I am not sure about this.

Comment: I don't see any reason not to. You can probably even have them in separate solution and add them as reference, but might be a bit harder to share common resources like connection string. I don't think the executable would be too big even if you have everything in one project. Maybe just 10-100MB.

Comment: Usually it's OK to have them all in a single project. You can simply arrange them in different folders. Sometimes you need to separate them in different class libraries and add a reference of them to the main project; such project break makes updates simpler. But there is no general rule for keeping them in a single project or break them to multiple projects. The size usually increase because of static resources, you can simply put them in satellite assemblies. I believe you can start your project using a single project and if you need refactor the project and break it to more class libraries.

Comment: @slai, I guess I will give the separate assemblies a try, this also seems to be suggested by Mr. Reza Aghaei.

Comment: The cumbersomeness of interprocess communication makes it preferable to have your application broken down into separate projects under one solution IMHO. I also have taken my forms, changed them to user controls and put them in a library. I then add them dynamically into a container control in the main form when needed.

Comment: @MarkHall, sounds like something I can also try, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Separating funcitionalities into multiple standalone apps (exe) and sharing temp files is a realy bad idea. There are limited scenarios that can benifit from this approach and I have a clue that your scenario is not one of them.

There are more better ways to share data between apps than sharing temporary files (WCF, .NET Remoting, MSMQ, Web Services, ...). You can imagine that running 100 exe apps will also burn a lot more resources that single one app with same functionalities. Your approch is also prone to file locking so be adviced to reconsider your solution.

Comment: Hi George, I am sure the idea is not that great, that is why I asked the question. In my case the 100 forms are not going to be run in the same session, Each form is for a separate function. Think of a case such as Excel. Almost each menue item leads to a separate dialogue. WCF is good to share remote data access, Remoting is/was good to share objects across servers,MSMQ is too complex for simple data passing,

Comment: I realy dont see the reason whay 100 forms can not be part of single app, but I see a nightmare for managing and debuging 100 separate apps. And as I have pointed earlier, chech Task Manager and you will see how much resources are drained to run simple .net app. Multiplying this usage by 100x is total waste of resources.

Comment: OK, so you are saying that firing small apps will consume resources. Debugging is not quiet an issue though because each unit is supposed to be unit tested on its own. Good point. Thx.

Comment: Of course, 100 apps will aproximatly consume 100x more resources that single one. Every time .NET loads Windows Form app a lot of Assemblies are loaded in App Domain.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes, it is ok to have 100 of forms in the same project, nothing special about that, it will also be faster to compile than tons of mini projects containing a few forms as C# compilation is very fast but having dependencies (or worse, nested dependencies) involves writing a lot to the disk (compile dll C, write it in output folder C, compile DLL B that depends on B, copy C to B folder, then compile project A that depends on B, and have it copy B.dll and C.dll to A etc etc).

It's impossible to tell you how to properly architect your solution without a LOT more information but on your specific question there is no reason to split your project just because it has a lot of form, nothing bad will happen as a result of it.